Bot does not accept new values Discord.js V14
While making a discord bot, I ran into a problem. My bot works with the values that were before it was launched, but when I try to change the value of a variable during its operation, it simply ignores and works the same way with the old values. Here is my connect command, the bot should connect to the voice channel I am in. When the command is run for the first time, it works, however, this is only if I was in the voice channel before the bot was launched. And if I switch to another channel, it just joins the channel I was in before the bot was launched. Please help, this is too hard for me.
connect command:
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    ]
});

module.exports = {
    name: 'connect',
    description: 'Connect the bot to a voice channel',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'channel_id',
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Channel,
            description: 'Select a voice channel to connect to',
            required: false,
            channelTypes: [2], // Голосовой канал
        }
    ],
    callback: async (client, interaction) => {
        await interaction.deferReply();

        try {
            

            let channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel_id');
            console.log('Selected channel:', channel ? channel.name : 'not provided');
    
            if (!channel) {
                if (interaction.member.voice?.channel) {
                    channel = interaction.guild.voice.channel.id;
                    console.log('Member channel:', channel.name);
                } else {
                    return interaction.editReply({ content: 'You are not in a voice channel and no valid channel ID was provided!' });
                }
            } 

            let connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: channel.id,
                guildId: channel.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });

            await interaction.editReply({ content: 'Successfully connected to the voice channel!' });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.editReply({ content: 'Failed to connect to the voice channel.' });
        }
    },
}

I have tried various ways to update the channel variable, but all to no avail, it does not change it.
